# Implementing infinite lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, infinite

Been trying really hard. Don't know where to go from here ..

I need to define a function that takes an integer and returns an infinitely repeating list of numbers from 0 to n-1.

```
    cycle n =
        let aux1 v1 n 
            |(v1 == n) = v1 : (aux1 0 n)
            | (v1<n) = v1 : (aux1 (v1 + 1) n)
        in aux1 0 n
```

Comment: Yours isn't the shortest solution, nor the most "functional", but it's close: I can fix your code by removing three characters. Why don't you show us what you're getting, and explain why you are stuck?

Comment: For a cleaner solution, you could look at `Enum` [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) and a couple of well chosen list functions [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html)

Comment: I get ambiguous occurrence 'cycle'. I just started Haskell yesterday, I don't even know what that means.

Comment: You can *qualify* the function call using `Main.cycle` (in GHCi) or `MyModule.cycle` if you are in a module, or by renaming your function. The problem is that you called your function `cycle`, which [already exists in the Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=cycle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cycle' n = [0..n-1] ++ cycle' n`

but i have to add some chars so stack overflow can accept such a short answer :)

Answer (score 4):

@piotrek

there is a even shorter solution:

```
cycle' n = [0..]>>[0..n-1]
```

Comment: That was a pretty neat way to interpret the list monad. I've never thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

```
cycle' n = xs
    where xs = take n [0 ..] ++ xs
```

Comment: Or `cycle' n = cycle [0 .. n-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

A nice and simple way to generate a lot of infinite series is using higher-order function (`map`,`filter`, `fold`) on a simple stream.

For example, here's two ways of generating an infinite series of natural even numbers:

```
evens = filter even [1..]
evens = map (*2) [1..]
```

Your problem can be easily solved using this method. You might want to check out what `mod` does. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
cycle' n = concat $ repeat [0..n-1]
```